# How do I validate a kerberos token (in node.js)?

Tags: node.js, authentication, kerberos, spnego

I'm not quite sure I have given the right description.

Bascially, I'm trying to add `Windows Authentication` to a node.js site.

I send back a `401` with the `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` header.

The browser immediately fires back an `authorization` header with the value `Negotiate <some string of characters>`

At this point, I just want to ensure the token is valid. I've tried to find examples of other open-source frameworks that do this, but I didn't really know what I was looking for.

Just to be clear, the user has already signed on to the domain and is not sending username/password information.

(I may not fully understand how all this works).

I just found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995330.aspx).

> Server decodes the NegTokenInit, extracts the supported MechTypes (the
>   one at the front of the MechTypeList should be either Kerberos Legacy
>   or Kerberos V5), ensures it is one of the expected ones, and then
>   extracts the MechToken and authenticates using
>   gss_accept_security_context.

If I understand it correctly, I'm looking for `gss_accept_security_context`.

I also tried to using `GSSManager` in java with no luck. I posted that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289231/using-gssmanager-to-validate-a-kerberos-ticket).

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently submitted a pull request for the kerberos module mentioned above (https://www.npmjs.org/package/kerberos) to implement server side authentication. Previously that module only had client side APIs implemented.

I have also created a passport authentication strategy, passport-negotiate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-negotiate) which utilizes this and implements server side HTTP authenication, including the 401 and the WWW-Authenticate.

You can see the details of it here:

https://github.com/dmansfield/passport-negotiate/blob/master/lib/passport-negotiate/strategy.js

Unfortunately, this won't work unless the pull request gets merged into the kerberos module and there's a new release, or you can get the patched version of kerberos from my github:

https://github.com/dmansfield/kerberos

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the source code of the node-expose-sspi module. Because it is doing exactly what you want to do : it validates a Kerberos/NTLM token with the SSPI function called `AcceptSecurityContext`.

https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi

Note : I am the author of this module.

Comment: "Requirements: Microsoft Windows OS, [...]"