# Random Kerberos validation error with Spring

Tags: java, spring, kerberos

I sometimes get in my application, say 1-10 times within 24h, the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull
...
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
```

Any ideas to how this error comes to be? As I said, it appears very random and does not happen very often.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289231/using-gssmanager-to-validate-a-kerberos-ticket?rq=1

Comment: I think in the post you linked to the problem is that the validation never succeeds. In my case the validation error is quite random and happens only a few times a day.

Comment: Show a sample ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients are probably sending NTLM tokens which JGSS cannot process.