# Can't get Kerberos realm

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos

I am new to Kerberos/hive, want to connect hive (Kerberos implemented) using JDBC.

```
> > org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new
> > org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
> >             conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
> >             UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
> >             UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("<principal>", "<path to keytab file>");
> > 
> > 
> > Class.forName(Util.getConstantProperty("hive.class.name"));
> > 
> > log.info("Making connection with Hive DB"); hiveConn =
> > DriverManager.getConnection("<hive db url>",,"hive.user","");
```

getting error:

```
2018-10-29 20:32:50 ERROR ConnectionHandler:80 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(HadoopKerberosName.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:299)
        at utils.ConnectionHandler.connectHiveDB(ConnectionHandler.java:58)
```

Comment: Copy `krb5.conf` file from the Kerberos server to the JobServer and run try. Also, try setting `<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
  <value>simple</value> 
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>` in `core-site.xml` in `Hadoop`.

Comment: Or `Put the krb5.conf file into the %JAVA_HOME%/lib/security directory, e.g. /opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/security/krb5.conf.`

Comment: getting error now: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:935)

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150158/errorjavaxsecurityauthloginloginexception-unable-t.html

Comment: Also, https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.5/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-kerb-1-4.html

Answer (score 1):

in addition the suggestion from Prazy in the comments

Don't forget to set the default realm in the krb5.conf

and if you still have problems add the kerberos debug into your comand line

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console
```

Comment: after doing, getting below error:  javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:935)

Comment: do you try logging in with the keytab directly?  kinit username@<REALM> -k -t mykeytab

Comment: also might be good to stick a file check to confirm that the keytab file is accessible

Comment: In java verified using f.canRead() that keytab file is accessible. @shainnif

Comment: does the name of the principle match what is in your kdc ( spn field if you are using Active directory), can you pass the -D variable into your java process?

Answer (score 1):

## Quick Explanation

If using a `krb5.conf`
ensure you have set

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm=EXAMPLE.COM
```

If not using a `krb5.conf` set both

- `java.security.krb5.kdc`
- `java.security.krb5.realm`

## Further Reading

For reference, source for [KerberosUtil](https://github.com/c9n/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/KerberosUtil.java)
And the underlying kerberos library [getDefaultRealm](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/Config.java#L978)

Notice that by default `getDefaultRealm` looks in your `krb5.conf` **default_realm**:

```
get("libdefaults", "default_realm");
```

There is another place `realm` can be defined.... via the property:

```
java.security.krb5.realm
```

This value is silently ignored, if the `kdc` is not ALSO defined via `java.security.krb5.kdc`

This fact is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/kerberos-requirements.html)